# How to toggle only THIS element in Vue

Tags: vue.js

New to working with Vue and I have a page with customers info on it (email, phone, name, address, payment info...). Each element can be clicked on to show an input form to edit the data selected. Here is my mark-up for the email element

```
<label>Email</label>
<div class="customer-email item editable">
   <div v-if="!edit_data" @click="editData">{{customer.email}}</div>
   <form v-if="edit_data">
      <input v-model="customer.email"></b-input>
      <button @click="saveData">Save</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

To achieve the functionality of hiding the data and showing the input to update the data I have the following:

```
data() {
  return {
     edit_data: false,
     customer: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
     }
  };
},
methods: {
    editData: function () {
       this.edit_data = !this.edit_data;
   },
}
```

All pretty straight forward. But if I have more than 1 element that can be edited how do I ONLY have this functionality effect the element clicked? If I had some mark-up like this:

```
<div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <div class="customer-email item editable">
            <div v-if="!edit_data" @click="editData">{{customer.email}}</div>

            <b-form v-if="edit_data">
                <b-input v-model="customer.email"></b-input>
                <button @click="saveData">Save</button>
            </b-form>
        </div>


        <label>Name</label>
        <div class="customer-name item editable">
            <div v-if="!edit_data" @click="editData">{{customer.name}}</div>

            <form v-if="edit_data">
                <input v-model="customer.email"></b-input>
                <button @click="saveData">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When one element is clicked they all open which makes sense. But that is NOT what I want, I only want to 'open' the element that was clicked.

I know how to address this the jQuery way.

```
$(element).click(function() {
    $(this).sibling(element).show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Or something similar.

So my question is... **Is there a best practice's Vue way to get this done??** Thanks in advance.

Comment: One way to do it, if you can get all your form elements in an array https://jsfiddle.net/tLbukj1r , the other way it is make a component and customize it with slots. I would suggest the first method.

Comment: You can use v-for loop and set to each element boolean property with false value by deafualt, for example isOpened. And then in your clickHandler you can select your element with index and set to true isOpened property.

Comment: @ValeriiVoronkov For my case that won't work as the elements that are editable are scattered throughout the page within different panels and divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component and make functionality inside this:

```js
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  template: '#custom-input',
  props: ['item', 'label'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      value: '',
      edit_data: false,
    }
  },

  methods: {
    editData: function() {
      this.edit_data = !this.edit_data;
    },
    saveData: function() {
      console.log('saved')
    },
  }

});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    edit_data: false,
    customer: {
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="custom-input">
  <div class="customer-email item editable">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <div v-if="!edit_data" @click="editData">{{item}}</div>
    <form v-if="edit_data">
      <input v-model="item">
      <button @click="saveData">Save</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>


<div id="app">
  <div>
    <custom-input :item="customer.email" :label="'email'"> </custom-input>
    <custom-input :item="customer.name" :label="'Name'"> </custom-input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like this approach but is it doable when working with Single File Components? Where I dont need to el prop to target the app. The only template on the page is already connected to the data and 'component template' , like you created, would be visible within the main template. Hope this makes sense. AND The only reusable components we are using with the project are ones that can be used on multiple Single File Components. This is something I only need on on-page.

Comment: Is the same way use it on Single File Components, But you need to create a `.vue` file necessarily

Comment: I appreciate your help! Like I mentioned I'm new to Vue. So when I added this to my SFC  I add your Vue.component snippet above my export default {}  so first thing in my script tag and got the error " 'Vue' is not defined (no-undef) " in my terminal.

Comment: `<script> Vue.componet('custom-input.....}; export default { data() {...} </script>` rough example of my code.

Comment: When you use a SFC, you must create a file an then import it into your page. see: https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html